# How to extract and store a word from a string C++

Tags: c++

I'm needing some help with extracting a word from a string. The string will be taken from a file, so I will not know where the word is or how long it is. The string below is for example. How can I take ('how) out and store it in the string word without knowing how long the word is? It could be 'google or 'dukemflopper, etc.

```
string text = "hi there, 'how are you today?" ; 
string apWord = {" '"} ;
int wstart = text.find(apWord) +1 ;
string word  ;
word = text.substr(wstart, /*???*/ ) ;
cout << word << endl ;
```

If I put the number of characters in the substr /???/ it works, but the issue is I don't know how to figure out that number of characters to grab the word from space to space. And to complicate matters further, the ' /' ' could be in the middle of the word, such as kit'ty.

```
string ouch = "Why are kit'ty cats think they're above us?"
int find = text.find(" ' ") ;
```

I also need to be able to grab "kit'ty" out of this string, not knowing where or how long the word is, if that makes sense. This applies to words starting with an ' or containing an ' somewhere. I need to be able to do both. The hard part is only using string and functions of that. ie, not using istringstream or vector, etc.

Comment: Use `std::istringstream` instead.

Comment: I am currently a student, and we have not went over istringstream, but an example is more than welcome!

Comment: In your example above you would be trying to find the word 'kitty' or 'ty'?

Comment: @Jeremy This [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) provides some examples. Lookup the constructor functions and the formatted stream extraction `operator>>()`.

Comment: Trying to find Kitty. There are random ' inserted into words. I need to extract those words in order to move or remove the apostrophe and put it back.

Comment: You need to tokenize your string, i.e. create a vector of tokens that compose your original string. For each token, just search for a \'.

Comment: Please describe your 'rules' a bit more clearly.  Do you simply need words that start OR contain an apostrophe?

Comment: I tried to explain the rules a bit better in the last paragraph. I have to use functions of string, like .find .erase, etc. I figured out how to move the apostrophe, so it works with one word. But I cannot figure out how to pull that word from the string.

Comment: Great.  Search and find your first apostrophe, then find the 'word' its on... Then process your word...Repeat to find more apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

Hier you can use the Regular expressions. For your example you can use:

(\w*'\w*)

This will give you the both words kit'ty and they're

You can try for example here https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think this function works for words beginning with the '. Second for the words with the ' in the middle. But not sure how to make sure it doesn't do this to the words that start with the '

```
void apBegin(string &text)
{
  string apWord = {" '"} ;
  int wstart = text.find(apWord) +1 ;
  int endword = 0 ;
  for (unsigned int i = wstart; i < text.length(); i++)
  {
    if (text[i] == ' ')
    {
      endword = i ;
      break ;
    }
  }
  string word = text.substr(wstart, endword - wstart ) ;
  word.erase(0, 1);
  word += "\' ";
  return ;
}

void apMiddle(string &text)
{
  string text = "once upon a time there were many 'dragons and cats!" ;
  string ap ={"'"} ;
  int location1 = text.find(ap) ;
  int startword = 0, endword = 0 ;
  for (unsigned int i = location1; i < text.length(); i++)
  {
      if (text[i] == ' ')
      {
          endword = i ;
          break ;
      }
  }
    for (unsigned int i = location1; i >0; i--)
  {
      if (text[i] == ' ')
      {
          startword = i + 1;
          break ;
      }
  }
  string otherWord = text.substr(startword, endword - startword) ;
  int found = otherWord.find(ap) ;
  otherWord.erase(found, 1) ;
  otherWord.insert(found + 1, "'") ; // moves ' one to the right.
}
```